# Making a Discord Loop

Tags: c#, visual-studio, discord, discord.net

I am currently making a bot for my server and I'm trying to make a function to when the bot receives .raid it spams messages I've tried loops but it keeps messing up my code. This is what I have for my C#. I just cant seem to get a loop working specifically in discord.

```
 //RAID
    private void RegisterRaidCommand()
    {
        commands.CreateCommand("raid")
             .Do(async (e) =>
             {
                 await e.Channel.SendMessage("READY SIR!");
                 //here is where the loop needs to start 
                //here is where the spam message goes

             });

    }
```

Comment: Have you tried connecting your code to the discord API? Read the documentation for more info: https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i made a spam/raid command using a normal for loop and it works fine for me. This command just takes in 2 parameters, one for the word or phrase that will be spammed and the int parameter for the amount of times you want it to be spammed.

```
[Command("spam")]
[RequireUserPermission(GuildPermission.Administrator)]
public async Task CMD14(int times, [Remainder] string Word)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < times; i++)
    {
        await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync($"`{Word}`");
    }
}
```

Hope this helps in some way, shape or form :)